# fortran cross-compiler for VxWorks PPC

Tags: gcc, fortran, cross-compiling, vxworks, powerpc

I have an i386 64 bit host with Windows 7 Enterprise and Ubuntu.
I have the entire folder with WorkBench (WindRiver development IDE) and target header files.

I need to compile Fortran code on i386 for a CES board running VxWorks on a PPC604 cpu.

I asked WindRiver and told me they did not develop and sell the cross-compiler anymore.

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you build a Fortran cross-compiler yourself? Or is it a requirement that you get commercial compiler support from somewhere? I suspect the only choice for the latter would be a custom contract with any of the remaining GCC support vendors.

Comment: I can build the cross-compiler (but I don't know how...) and I don't need a commercial support.

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think anyone ships pre-built Fortran cross-compilers for VxWorks.  The GNU project generally does not distribute binaries (only sources), and the usual suspects do not have them, either.  So you need to build a cross-compiler yourself.  There are some indications that `gfortran` (the GNU Fortran compiler) is expected to work on VxWorks, but I haven't tried this myself.

Here are some resources to get you started:

- [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) (search for *cross compiler*)
- [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.github.io/)

I strongly recommend to build the cross compiler on a GNU/Linux platform because it's more likely that the build scripts will work there out-of-the-box.